# Unusual bug with structs

Tags: c++, for-loop, struct, tokenize

In this program I need to read in information from a text file, the first line is the number of courses I am reading in to process information for, the next "chunk" of lines are the names of the courses, and the last "chunk" of lines list the class number for which that particular course is a prerequisite for. So,

```
18 //number of courses to read in
CSC111 //course 1
CSC112 //course 2
etc....
2    6  //course 1 is a prereq for course 2 and 6
7    8    9    11    15  //course 2 is prereq for course 7,8,9,11,15
etc....
```

I've figured out to tokenize the lines, and I need to put the information about how many dependencies a given course has into a "Course" struct, with one variable being "numDependencies." I have declared an array of N+1 course objects(indexing starting at 1, not 0). So numDepenedencies at Course 1 should be 2, numDependencies at Course 2 should be 5, and so on. The problem is once I reach course 11 my numDependencies variable somehow gets set to values like 297796848, and I can't figure out why. Here is my Course struct and main

```
typedef struct Course
{
    int numDependencies;
    int numPrerequisites;
    string name;
    int dependencies[6];
} Course;

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include "Course.h"
using namespace std; 

int main()
{

    int N;  //Number of courses
    ifstream infile("CSCCourses.txt");
    if (infile.fail()){
        cout << "File not found." << endl;
        //exit(0);
    }
    //read in number of courses
    infile >> N;
    //dynamically allocate array of courses
    Course* courseArray = new Course[N+1];
    //loop N times to read course names
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++){
        infile >> courseArray[i].name;
        cout << courseArray[i].name << endl;
    }
    //loop again to read course information
    //string str; //maybe this variable should be declared here?
    for (int j = N; j <= N+12; j++) 
    {
        cout << "Course " << j - N << endl;
        string str;
        getline(infile, str);
        //Skip delimiters
        string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(" ", 0);
        //Find first non delimiter
        string::size_type pos = str.find_first_of(" ", lastPos);
        while (string::npos != pos || string::npos != lastPos)
        {
            //Found token, put prereqs in course
            string numAsStr = str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos);
            //convert numasstr to integer
            int num = atoi(numAsStr.c_str());
            cout << num << endl;
            //use integer to set values properly in array of courses
            if(num != 0) {
                courseArray[j].numDependencies++;
            }
            lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(" ", pos);
            //find next non delimiter
            pos = str.find_first_of(" ", lastPos);
        }

        int number = courseArray[j].numDependencies;
        cout << "Number of dependencies is " << number << endl;
        cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
    }
infile.close();
```

}

Comment: Also, I know in the second for loop it doesn't go far enough. I set that since thats the point where the program goes wrong. I've gotten it to the proper values before by messing with the conditions of the second for loop, but it hasn't worked twice in a row.

Comment: You debugged your program line by line? _"gets set to values like 297796848"_ looks like you have used uninitialilzed values, hitting undefined behavior or reading out of bounds values.

Comment: _`for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++){`_ Any array indexing in c or c++ starts with `0` and needs to be less than `N` (not less or equal).

Comment: I have. If I run the program several times, the values will be 100% correct every 5th time or so. They are either all correct or I get values like those.

Comment: _"the values will be 100% correct every 5th time or so."_ LOL that's a pretty inappropriate rate :)

Comment: I think your loop is creating numbers larger than your computer/server can handle, so it is using the max.

Comment: Hahaha thats true, more like 1/5th correct! I've adjusted both of the loops in different ways, and I still get the same result.

Comment: Don't use `typedef struct` in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add next code before your **while** loop:

```
    courseArray[j].numDependencies = 0;
```

**EDIT**:

Original answer is kinda wrong. I overlooked how you are allocating that array.

Actual problem is next: you are allocationg N+1 elements and trying access N+2, N+3 etc. elements. So you should either do:

```
Course* courseArray = new Course[N+13];
```

instead of

```
Course* courseArray = new Course[N+1];
```

or change accessing elements code like this (note "**-N**" code):

```
    if(num != 0) {
        courseArray[j-N].numDependencies++;

    int number = courseArray[j-N].numDependencies;
```

Comment: Emm... Not so obvious now for me. See my EDIT.

Comment: Your original answer still makes sense, since I have two different for loops. I go through the course array once to get the course name, but I go through it again to add information to it. The way the file is read in is kind of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You have dimensioned your array as `Course* courseArray = new Course[N+1];` but then your second for loop is `for (int j = N; j <= N+12; j++)`, which will go beyond the array's boundary. Of course, immediately after that you are fixing it by using `cout << "Course " << j - N << endl;`, but then you have forgotten to do it again with `courseArray[j].numDependencies++;` and `int number = courseArray[j].numDependencies;`

But why are you initializing j to N and doing 13 iterations? You should do N! As I said above, using j-N should solve it, but a better solution would be to fix the second for loop by making it identical to the first one, like this:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++){
```

and of course if you do this you must also fix your cout, using `j` instead of `j - N`.